# How to convert array to a mathematical computation expression?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to write a computation mathematical expression and store each sign into an array.

For example, I want to convert the array:

```
let arr = ['10', '-', '(', '2', '+', '1', ')', '*', '3'];
```

To the following expression:

```
let result = 10 - (2 + 1) * 3;  // 1
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: `eval(arr.join(' '))`

Comment: Mate I corrected it. You haven't clicked new changed link.

Comment: You can create your own calculator as well. We did it in college to practice stacks (for arrays it's the use of `push` and `pop`). Pretty much you keep pushing numbers to one array and operators to the other array. When you find something that has higher precedence, you handle it in place. You do this until the arrays are empty.

Comment: Yes, that is what I practice currently :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not validate your input but `eval(arr.join(""))` will do it.
[`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) takes a string and executes it as it were a js expression.

Comment: I forgot I can use eval() to achieve this goal. Thank you so much

Comment: No problem, but keep in mind that this will only work if the expression is valid. Also, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/198031/1918287) before using `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

> It work only with `eval`,
>
> `new Function` is not working for this issue

```js
const arr = ['10', '-', '(', '2', '+', '1', ')', '*', '3'];

eval(arr.join(' ')); // 1
```